# While loop not executing inside callback

Tags: javascript

Inside the catch of a promise

```
.catch((message) => {
        console.log(message)
        var newUrl = url
        chrome.tabs.create({url: newUrl}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.status)
            status = 'loading'
            while (status == 'loading') {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log(response.status)
                    status = response.status
                }, 3000)
            }
        })
    })
```

I'm trying to write the catch in the way that it will open up a new page, wait for it to finish loading, then grab the new cookies

I feel like Im taking crazy pills as this seems super straight forward. However its never printing out `response.status`

I want it to wait to check `response.status` every 3 seconds and once the page has `loaded` it will end the loop.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably this-> https://stackoverflow.com/a/37728255/909535 ?

Comment: oooooh, I'm not used to Javascript....this makes sense

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setTimeout() method inside a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728184/settimeout-method-inside-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way You've wrote it you've made an infinite loop, which will put tons of `setTimeout`s on browser's event queue.

`setTimeout` also put's code there, but it puts it with "3sec plus" delay note.

In practice you tell your browser - set infinite timeouts for me, and after it's finished, please do console.log after 3 seconds. This won't happen.

You should probably use `setInterval` instead